# button.onclick=func; not appearing in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I add an `onclick` attribute to an input via JS, it doesn't show up in the HTML but it executes the function. If I add the input via HTML, it shows the `onlick` attribute but it doesn't work. See

`button.onclick=toggleNav;`

```js
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.type = "button";
button.value = "JS Btn";
button.onclick = toggleNav;
document.body.prepend(button);

function toggleNav() {
  $("nav").toggle("slow");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="toggleNav" value="HTML btn">
<nav>Test</nav>
```

What is wrong? Thanks

Comment: `onclick="toggleNav"` should be `onclick="toggleNav()"`

Answer (score 2):

You should run the function inside the `onclick` attribute instead of just declaring it.

changed this `onclick="toggleNav"` to this `onclick="toggleNav()"`

```js
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.type = "button";
button.value = "JS Btn";
button.onclick = toggleNav;
document.body.prepend(button);

function toggleNav() {
  $("nav").toggle("slow");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="toggleNav()" value="HTML btn">
<nav>Test</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

> If add the input via html it shows the onlick attribute but it doesnt work

Cause you need to invoke the handler:

```
 onclick="toggleNav(event)"
```

> i add an onclick attribute to an input via JS, it doesn't show up in the html but it executes the function.

Why do you think that it should show up somewhere?

Comment: Thanks,
If I inspect the HTML of both buttons:
`
<input value="JS Btn" type="button">
<input onclick="toggleNav()" value="HTML btn" type="button">
`

Only one has the onlick attribute in it. Both do work,but i dont understand why the eventhandler is "hidden".

Comment: @propper cause its not a html property but a DOM property. You can find it under the right tab of the element inspection tab.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, you are not calling the function in `onclick`. You need to call it like

```
onclick="toggleNav()"
```

```js
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.type = "button";
button.value = "JS Btn";
button.onclick = toggleNav;
document.body.prepend(button);

function toggleNav() {
  $("nav").toggle("slow");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" onclick="toggleNav()" value="HTML btn">
<nav>Test</nav>
```